# Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers

Tags: webserver, http, page-speed

I just finished a website that I designed and submitted it to [Google PageSpeed Insights](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) for performance reviews, and this is the results I got:

[image]

It says I need to set expiry date or a maximum age in the the HTTP headers, but I don't know how it is possible to set the expiry date for anything other than cookies/sessions, so I have no clue what this means or how to do it.